How is it that the finally block gets executed without exceptions but not the log.info after the logic?
I have the following piece of code:
logger.info("Checkpoint 1")
try:
    queue.push(item) # This is where the exception could occur
    logger.info("Checkpoint 2")
except queues.errors.NotAllowedError as exc:
    logger.info("Error 1")
    raise exc
except Exception as e:
    logger.info("Error 2")
finally:
    logger.info("Checkpoint 3")

I'd expect either the program to print (if all goes well):
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 2
Checkpoint 3

And if it goes wrong it should for example print:
Checkpoint 1
Error 2
Checkpoint 3

But in my case my program prints out:
Checkpoint 1
Checkpoint 3

In what situation could this ever happen? Does Exception not cover all exceptions that can happen?

Is the exception being raised not an Exception? The only way this could be is if it's a BaseException (which would be very unusual), or if you're shadowing Exception with something else. Are you getting a traceback after this, or does the exception appear to be caught?

Note probably not related to your issue but I think when you re-raise and exception you just do raise not raise exc (line 7)

@DavidWaterworth does that produce the same result? Is it also more accepted code?

@deceze I do not receive a traceback in this codebase. No process seems to quit so I assume the Exception is getting caught

Can you produce an actual [mre] that we can run? (Currently the implementation of queue is not defined here, so we can't use this as is.)

Are you confident that queues.errors.NotAllowedError is an actual exception class and/or is a valid expression? That's the only two things I can think that would cause this behaviour. It would cause another exception to be thrown. But maybe something is silently swallowing that exception (eg. outside your code block).

@deceze it is a quite complex codebase. Here is the implementation of push. When I looked at it I could not find a reason what exception wouldnt be caught

That is an interesting theory @Dunes, the exception only recently started happening so I am certain It does exist. But I will test the code without using that exception.

@Souf149 my understanding is it's not the same, including the original exception when you re-raise the error results in a messed up stack trace. So simply using raise is "best practice" in my opinion. See https://www.markbetz.net/2014/04/30/re-raising-exceptions-in-python/

Thanks to the comments, I was able to figure out that the exception was not being caught. After doing
except:
  self.logger.info(traceback.format_exc())

I was able to find out it was a ValueError triggering because my database model didnt match from the type of the queue. No idea why ValueError didn't trigger from my except Exception cause. But it has been fixed now. Thank you for everything.
I also learnt that BaseException does not trigger when doing except Exception which might have been an answer for this question.

A ValueError is an Exception, so that should have triggered. Again, have you redefined the name Exception in your code perchance…?

@deceze when I look for "Exception =" in my codebase I can not find anything. So I doubt Exception has been redefined.
